# Force JLabel Subclass to be displayed

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, subclassing

I have a class, that extends JLabel, to display an image on the whole innerArea of the label.
To achieve this, I overwrite paintComponent like this:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);

    if(image != null) {
        SwingUtilities.calculateInnerArea(this, innerArea);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, innerArea.width, innerArea.height, this);
    }

}
```

I thought it should work using a Constructor as follows:

```
public ImageLabel(String img) {

    super();
    this.image = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(img)).getImage();
    repaint();

}
```

But there I have the issue, that the Label has basically no size, since it has no actual content.
When using `super(" ");` instead everything looks as I actually expected.

Now I am wondering - is that a legit way to approach this issue or am I missing some other (probably better) way?

Comment: Why don't you simply call `new JLabel(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(img)).getImage())`?

Comment: As far as I found out, that way the ImageIcon won't be resized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though technically you *can* paint on a `JLabel`, it is preferable to paint on a `JPanel`. The code you have seems to be fine, just transer it to a `JPanel` instead.

> "But there I have the issue, that the Label has basically no size, since it has no actual content."

When painting, you want to remember to override `getPreferredSize()` also. paint isn't really content, so there will no preffered size. The reason, it works with by passing a parameter is that the String you pass to it is content, and that makes make the preferred size of the label match the String you pass to it. But like I said, use a `JPanel` like this

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    private final int D_W = 400;
    private final int D_W = 400;
    private BufferedIMage imag;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    }

    @Override 
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(D_W, D_H);
    }
}
```

Comment: So I was on the right way at least, thank you for making this more clear!

Answer (score 1):

peeskillet already gave an appropriate answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21401576/3182664 ). However, in order to achieve the usual behavior (that is, to obey the general contract that is set up by the `Component#setPreferredSize(Dimension)` method), the `getPreferredSize()` method should actually be overridden like this:

```
@Override 
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
        return super.getPreferredSize();
    }
    return new Dimension(D_W, D_H);

    // Could also return this, to make the panel's 
    // preferred size match the image size
    //return new Dimension(image.getWidth(this), image.getHeight(this));
}
```